# How write a simple command line tool in C?

Tags: c, ncurses

I want to write in C a command line tool with the following requirements:

- Few commands (<10)
- History management through the arrows key
- Capability to delete what I typed previously with baskspace
- Capability to add keyborad shortcuts such as ctrl+l to clear the screen
- Protable across UNIX systems

I am not asking for code here, but for indications about where to start. I first made some experiments with "scanf" and it quickly become quite complicated. I then looked at ncurses, and it seems also quite low level. Is there any C libraries dedicated to this task, where would you start ?

Comment: there is a new SE site http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ that is more suited for your question

Comment: @Scis I don't want to parse command line options, but create a "commandline tool" such as a very very simplified shell

Comment: @ManuelSelva My bad :) I understood the few 'Few commands' part the wrong way...

Comment: @bolov Sorry I missed your comment, is there a way to move my question other there ?

Comment: just astk this question there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The GNU Readline library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) is exactly designed for that.

Answer (score 2):

> I then looked at ncurses, and it seems also quite low level

[CDK (Curses Development Kit)](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/) - high-level wrapper over `ncurses`. I've had successful experience with it. When you need you always can use `ncurses` directly.